# test bootstrap modal element NoSuchElementError - Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I tried to check online bootstrap modal

> ./usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/elementexplorer.js https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
element(by.id('modal')).element(by.tagName('button')).click();
element(by.css('btn btn-primary'));
There was a webdriver error: NoSuchElementError No element found
```

How can i interaction with a button in modal box?
some advice?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$('.modal-dialog').element(by.buttonText('OK')).getText()
```

Comment: do you know why element(by.css('.modal-dialog')).element(by.buttonText('OK')).getText() doesn't works?

Comment: I didn't try  `element(by.css('.modal-dialog'))`.  `element(by.css())` is equivalent to `$()`. It should return the same element